# Querying XML data with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database, t-sql

I have a log table with XML column. I studied several examples of querying XML but they don't match my needs.

```
Id   TimeStamp            Message    Properties
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    2015-10-27 08:45:38  Text       <properties><property key="time">23.10.2015 15:00:40</property><property key="interceptors">False</property></properties>
2    2015-10-27 09:21:09  Text       <properties><property key="Product">Azure</property><property key="Source">Azure Infrastructure</property></properties>
3    2015-10-27 16:51:32  Text       <properties><property key="Product">Azure</property><property key="Source">Azure Infrastructure</property><property key="Uptime">00:00:27.3874982</property></properties>
4    2015-10-28 11:03:25  Text       <properties><property key="Uptime">00:19:21.4729461</property></properties>
```

I want to have a result set of all node values where the property node has a key of 'uptime'. The result set could look like:

```
Id   Uptime
-----------------
3    00:00:27.3874982
4    00:19:21.4729461
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one method which uses xquery expression with an attribute filter along with a CTE to avoid repeating the expression:

```
WITH Uptimes AS (
    SELECT
          Id
        , Properties.value('(/properties/property[@key="Uptime"])[1]', 'time(7)') AS Uptime
    FROM dbo.test
    )
SELECT Id, Uptime
FROM Uptimes
WHERE Uptime IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below sql

```
select id, act.value('(/properties/property[@key="Uptime"])[1]', 'varchar(25)')
from #t
where act.exist('/properties/property[@key="Uptime"]') = 1
```